# error C2971 a variable with non-static storage duration cannot be used as a non-type argument

Tags: c++, templates

Here is a simple example (the idea is to avoid a huge `if..else` or `switch` block inside a function):

```
namespace foo {
   enum class VALUES : int { val_0 = 0, val_1 = 1 };

   template<VALUES T>
   void print();

   template<>
   void print<VALUES::val_0>() { std::cout << "val_0\n"; }

   template<>
   void print<VALUES::val_1>() { std::cout << "val_1\n"; }

   void bar(int type) {
      VALUES v = static_cast<VALUES>(type);
      print<v>(); //error C2971 - "v" is a non-constant argument at compile-time
   }
};
```

The question is how to call `print<...>()` based on the `bar`'s parameter?
Please **do not suggest** to use `if..else` or `switch`.

Comment: Template arguments must be known at compile time. If the argument isn't known at compile time - you can't use it as a template argument.

Comment: If templates are out, and you shudder to even think about `if`/`else` or `switch`, last option would be to use `std::(unordered_)map`, but `switch` is generally superior over map.

Comment: What's wrong with using `if`/`else` or a good old `switch`?

Comment: @churill I want to speed up some functionality. `if/else` spends some time to choose a branch

Comment: @Dmitrii So how, if it was possible, would the runtime decide which template specialization to call? Magic? It would also need to choose a branch, no?

Comment: @churill I was thinking about template metaprogramming but at the moment have a solution also with multiple `if/else` and it uses static functions which I also want to avoid due to some specifics, moreover the solution is even slower

Comment: But templates don't exist at runtime. Templates are just a mechanism to generate a family of functions (or classes, etc.) . If it's just about printing the enum a simple `switch` should be the fastest. Templates are the wrong approach here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66171400/15104979
we just need a storage for all those functions and also they can be not templated. Also for non-members the Callback can be defined like `using Callback = void(*)();`. But we have to measure both cases: with `if/else` and `Callback`, specifically for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are deduced at compile time. Which means that those template arguments are constant (at compile time). In your case, `int type` is not a constant type and so is `VALUES v`. In order to resolve `v` at compile time, you need to mark is as `constexpr VALUES v;` and which also means that you need to initialize it with values. In this case, with compile time resolvable values. That's why this works,

```cpp
constexpr VALUES v = VALUES::val_0;
print<v>();
```

But not this,

```cpp
VALUES m = VALUES::val_0;
constexpr VALUES v = m;    // As soon as you do this, it is no longer resolvable at compile time.
print<v>();
```

So the simplest answer is, you will have to use `if`/`else`, `switch` or templates to get it done.