# std::function in std::unordered_map, error C3867 non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Tags: c++, c++11, std, unordered-map

I try to replace `if/else` by using a map to call some api

why the initializer list throws the error?

```
...
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>

class MyClass final : public Base
{
   std::string InfoInquiry(Class_1& request, Class_2& response);
   std::string ActivateDeactivate(Class_1& request, Class_2& response);
   ...
   using Callback = std::function<std::string(Class_1&, Class_2&)>;
   const std::unordered_map<std::string, Callback> m_ApiCalbacks{ //error C3867: 'MyClass ::InfoInquiry': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
      {"INFO", InfoInquiry},
      {"ACTIVATE_DEACTIVATE", ActivateDeactivate},
      ...
   };
}
```

note: `static` is not allowed in this case because it's in a dll and reloading the dll gets problems

Comment: `{"INFO", [this](Class_1& request, Class_2& response) { return InfoInquiry(request, response); }}`?

Comment: a member function is not a free function. You need an object to call it.

Comment: btw the error you get is just a symptom of the actual issue. You need `&` to get a pointer to a member function, but then still `&InfoInquiry` doesnt fit into a map of `Callback`s

Comment: maybe duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400257/how-can-i-pass-a-class-member-function-as-a-callback (though the answer I was hoping for I didnt see there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would argue for using [pointers-to-members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions) for this. `std::function` comes with a cost (at least one extra indirection, i.e. slow).

Something like this (edited for brevity):

```
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
public:
    std::string InfoInquiry() { return "info!"; }
    std::string ActivateDeactivate() { return "activate!"; }
    using Callback = std::string (MyClass::*) ();
    const std::map<std::string, Callback> m_ApiCalbacks {
       {"INFO", &MyClass::InfoInquiry},
       {"ACTIVATE_DEACTIVATE", &MyClass::ActivateDeactivate}
    };
    std::string Call(std::string const& name) {
        auto it = m_ApiCalbacks.find(name);
        if (it == m_ApiCalbacks.end()) // optional check if name is valid
            return "???";
        return (this->*(it->second))();
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass c;
    std::cout << c.Call("INFO") << "\n";
    std::cout << c.Call("ACTIVATE_DEACTIVATE") << "\n";
    std::cout << c.Call("X") << "\n";
}
```

Bonus note: in some C++ implementations, `std::map` is faster than `std::unordered_map`. Check to be sure. ([Live demo](https://quick-bench.com/q/00OSTiExGcAxhcLw7anJz2qPMTQ))

Answer (score 1):

Part of what isn't said (except in some replies) is that you're trying to call member functions, and that *requires* you to have a pointer (or reference, or whatever) to the class instance you're calling.  You *can* wrap that up into your map if you wish.  You don't need to in this case, as your map "lives" inside the class, and thus you don't have to, but here's a way to do it if you'd like.

I'm taking rustyx's implementation, and changing it slightly to show another way of doing this, preserving your original signatures of the callee methods.

```
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
public:
    std::string InfoInquiry(Class_1& request, Class_2& response) { return "info!"; }
    std::string ActivateDeactivate(Class_1& request, Class_2& response) { return "activate!"; }
    using Callback = std::function<std::string(Class_1&, Class_2&)>;
    const std::map<std::string, Callback> m_ApiCalbacks {
       {"INFO", std::bind(&MyClass::InfoInquiry, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)},
       {"ACTIVATE_DEACTIVATE", std::bind(&MyClass::ActivateDeactivate, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)}
    };
    std::string Call(std::string const& name, Class_1& c1, Class_2& c2) {
        auto it = m_ApiCalbacks.find(name);
        if (it == m_ApiCalbacks.end()) // optional check if name is valid
            return "???";
        return (it->second)(c1, c2);
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass c;
    Class_1 local_c1{};
    Class_2 local_c2{};
    std::cout << c.Call("INFO", local_c1, local_c2) << "\n";
    std::cout << c.Call("ACTIVATE_DEACTIVATE", local_c1, local_c2) << "\n";
    std::cout << c.Call("X", local_c1, local_c2) << "\n";
}
```

This preserves the ability to call the methods with arbitrary arguments through the usage of `std::bind` to make a callable function that has the signature you want, while also keeping a pointer to your instance.  If you ever do this *outside* of your class though, be sure you don't use a dangling pointer.  Here, `this` is used and your map lives as long as your class, but if your `bind` target is another class, make sure it doesn't point to an object that doesn't exist anymore when you try and call it.

Answer (score 0):

The error states, what to do. But it only works on static functions that simple.

```
class MyClass : public Base {
    static std::string InfoInquiry(Class_1& request, Class_2& response);
    static std::string ActivateDeactivate(Class_1& request, Class_2& response);

    using Callback = std::function<std::string(Class_1&, Class_2&)>;
    const std::unordered_map<std::string, Callback> m_ApiCalbacks {
        {"INFO", &MyClass::InfoInquiry},
        {"ACTIVATE_DEACTIVATE", &MyClass::ActivateDeactivate},
    };
};
```

Since `m_ApiCalbacks` is const, using static member functions makes sense.

Comment: "Since you declared `m_ApiCalbacks` as const"... the returned value is `const`, but thats not really relevant

Comment: `static` is not allowed in this case because it's in a dll and reloading the dll gets problems

Comment: See [Store pointers to member function in the map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/630994/4434064)

Comment: @Dmitrii Concerning _`static` is not allowed in this case because it's in a dll and reloading the dll gets problems_: Such constraints should've been mentioned in the question.